# Couldn't send push notification using Azure Notification Hubs

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to create a notification bus to send push notifications to my windows phone App.

I referred the [link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-phone-get-started/) and followed all the steps.

My application is registering httpchannel

```
var channel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find("MyPushChannel");
        if (channel == null)
        {
            channel = new HttpNotificationChannel("MyPushChannel");
            channel.Open();
            channel.BindToShellToast();
        }

        channel.ChannelUriUpdated += async (o, args) =>
        {
            var hub = new NotificationHub("xyz", "Endpoint=sb://xyz-ns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=DWNOTQgqiKsDsTpXx4kUyeBPLsdSlFEP2YZIMW1dMEU=");
            await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(args.ChannelUri.ToString());
        };
```

And the console application

```
private static async void SendNotificationAsync()
    {
        var hub = NotificationHubClient
            .CreateClientFromConnectionString("Endpoint=sb://xyz-ns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=6P1isg5Uv97hJxRqbvJ11yJL+UV49RTSZNALJAoVCzI=",
            "xyz");
        const string toast = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                             "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
                             "<wp:Toast>" +
                             "<wp:Text1>Hello from a .NET App!</wp:Text1>" +
                             "</wp:Toast> " +
                             "</wp:Notification>";
        await hub.SendMpnsNativeNotificationAsync(toast);
    }
```

I have even enabled unauthorized notifications in the portal. However when I run the console application, I am unable to get the notification.

And My console application looks like this

```
static void Main()
    {
        SendNotificationAsync();
    }
```

Can somebody help me what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Hi. How do you call the SendNotificationAsync() in your Main method?

Comment: @efimovandr Its just a normal Main method which calls the function. I have edited the question. Please check.

Comment: I need to know what step I am missing in this. Is there a way to check whether the service is up and running and receiving the messages I send? And to verify it is pushing the notifications to devices.

Comment: Do SendNotificationAsync().Wait();